# Format ping success and failure output

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to get the ping command to out put both success and failures with the time taken to a file.

I have tried using 'if errorlevel 1' without success

here is my current code

```
@echo off
set /p IP=IP: 
:top
for /F "tokens=7 delims==< " %%A in ('ping -n 1 %IP% ^| find "TTL"') do (
    if errorlevel 1 ( echo Failed>> output.txt) else ( echo Successful! Time=%%A>> output.txt )
)
goto top
```

What I want this script to do is on a successful ping output "Successful! Time=" and on an unsuccessful ping output "Failed".

But what it is actually doing is out putting successful pings no problem but it freezes on failed pings.

Comment: Did you try [searching](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5Dping+success+failure) using `[batch-file]ping success failure` because it is a fairly regular question.

Comment: @Compo I have but, I haven't found the answer I've been looking for because they don't work with the for loop that is finding the time taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`ErrorLevel`](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) is not going to show the return error value of the [`ping`](https://ss64.com/nt/ping.html)/[`find`](https://ss64.com/nt/find.html) command line since it is executed by [`for /F`](https://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) in a new [`cmd`](https://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html) instance.

Do something like this instead:

```
@echo off
set /P IP="IP: "
>> "output.txt" (
    ping -n 1 %IP% | > "ttl.tmp" find "TTL=" && (
        for /F "usebackq tokens=5* delims=:<=> " %%A in ("ttl.tmp") do @echo Successful! %%B
    ) || (
        echo Failed
    )
    del "ttl.tmp"
)
```

The [`&&` and `||` symbols](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) constitute conditional execution operators that react on the [exit code](https://ss64.com/nt/errorlevel.html) of the `find` command. The output of `find` is written to a temporary file, which is then read and parsed by another [`for /F` loop](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) (just edit `tokens=` and `delims=` to your needs).

Comment: @ashipfl I was wondering if there is a way I could get both the time and the TTL